# Show hidden row on parent row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have rows but one row one row is hidden and I need to show them when I click on parent row link .btn-link ...

So when I click on 'details' - class="btn-link" I need to show the next row who has class "showDetails" and who is hidden

On click nothing happens. Why does my code not work?

```js
$(".btn-link").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr.showDetails').show();
});
```

```css
.showDetails {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn-link"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Details
      </a>
    </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2017-01-04</span></td>
    <td>£46.00</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="label label-table label-success">Paid</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showDetails">
    <td colspan="20">
      <table id="" class="table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Recipient</th>
            <th>Expiry</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-6">
              <p class="detailCell">Three Course Italian Meal for Two with Prosecco at Michelin Recommended Mele e Pere, Soho</p>
            </td>
            <td>46.00</td>
            <td>No recipient</td>
            <td>Mar 11, 2017</td>
            <td><span class="label label-warning">Paid</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Please check what closest does `$(this).closest('tr').next().show();`

Comment: I try but dont work,

Comment: See my answer. It does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest is not doing what you think it does.
It goes up the DOM looking for the TR. Then you need the NEXT tr

```js
$(".btn-link").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.showDetails {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn-link"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Details
      </a>
    </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2017-01-04</span></td>
    <td>£46.00</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="label label-table label-success">Paid</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="showDetails">
    <td colspan="20">
      <table id="" class="table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Recipient</th>
            <th>Expiry</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-6">
              <p class="detailCell">Three Course Italian Meal for Two with Prosecco at Michelin Recommended Mele e Pere, Soho</p>
            </td>
            <td>46.00</td>
            <td>No recipient</td>
            <td>Mar 11, 2017</td>
            <td><span class="label label-warning">Paid</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: thanks this works, but how to toggle... so on next click to hide that row?

Comment: Toggle! - see update - also please have a look at the documentation